# Representativity of a sample to a reference population with a mixed distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, correlation, sampling, posterior

I a have a series of small samples taken not randomly from a reference population with a complex distribution over a categoric variable with 21 levels and a continuous one in the x > 0 domain.

I would like to check which of these samples is more representative of the reference distribution. 
My approach until now has been to divide the continuous variable into 20 groups, compute the frequency of the combination of the two variables (now both categorical) and compare it with the same combinations in the samples.
For the comparison, I thought of using either Cramer V or Spearman correlation or the multiplication of both.

Does it make sense? which of the three correlation methods (cramer, spearman, multiplication of both) should I use?

Another nicer possibility would be to use the posterior probability of the population distribution given the sample, using the second answer to this: [Probability that a sample came from a known distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/380509/probability-that-a-sample-came-from-a-known-distribution?rq=1), but I'm not sure how to build the prior (should I just set it to 1?).

Finally, these methods are based on the arbitrary subdivision of the continuous variable in 20 groups. It would be better to able to use the variable as continuous but I wouldn't know how.

Comment: As Tim answered in the link you included, you can use log likelihood to determine how likely the sample is given a true reference, this works for any distribution.

Comment: Just the likelyhood and not the full posterior p(M|y)? What about a solution to avoid the categorization of the continuous variable?

Comment: The frequentist approach does not require a prior (and there is no posterior). I do not know what exactly you are doing with the categorization, but likelihood does not require it.

Comment: I use categorization because I don't know the distribution form of the continuous variable given each level of the categorical one. So discretizing it helps me create an empirical probability distribution along the two variables; then I simply need to assign the probability to the data points.

Comment: What do you mean by "representative"? The correlation is just a number, which in an overwhelmingly large number of cases is a number with little to no meaning. If you consider how the correlation is computed, you only get a seriously reduced piece of information.

Comment: I need to find which sample (obtained through different non-random methods) is more similar to the original population of origin, of which I have the data.

Comment: @Bakaburg: now the question is what you mean by "similar". You need to first decide, which property you want to reproduce. Same mean? Same variance? Same nth order moment, central moment, etc. If you'd like to test whether the "distributions" are compatible, you could do the rather weak Kolmogorov–Smirnov test, but this is only for 1D distributions. Since you state that your distribution is complex with an additional dimension (the categorical var), you first have to figure out a measure what "likeness" means.

Comment: mmmm, more likely to be sampled from it? more likely that a measurement made on  the sample would be similar to one done on the population (or a random sample of it)? Digging around I restricted the field to three methodologies: chi-square goodness of fit, rmse of the observed and expected probabilities, likelihood comparison.